# Using gradle to build apks with different resources without flavours

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

I have an application that should be branded (colors, graphic assets) according to requirements of different customers.

Until now, I used flavours for doing this.

Currently, my project contains a lot of flavours, and I feel that this solution is not scalable (my project already has more than 10 flavours and counting).

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to have a build flow that generates several apks with different configurations using gradle in a more organised way?

Comment: "I feel that this solution is not scalable" -- please describe what you would consider to be scalable. "in a more organised way?" -- please describe what you would consider to be "more organised".

Comment: It is very likely that I will need to build 10-20 apks (or more) that are themed differently. Creating a flavour for each and every apk is an option, however, I feel like it will create a mess out of my project + will increase development time (switching between flavours...). What I am looking for is maybe have a build flow in which I have folders with assets per brand (for example), and the build flow simply builds an apk out of the project's source code with the proper adjustments. I hope this is clearer :)

Comment: "will increase development time (switching between flavours...)" -- why are you switching between flavors at development time? Have one flavor that is your baseline for development, and stick with that, and only worry about the other flavors when you want to bulk-build new versions of your app from the command line (or build server or whatever). "What I am looking for is maybe have a build flow" -- and your flow description is precisely what product flavors are. I still do not understand what you are seeking that is different than product flavors.

Comment: My project is actually a bit more complex than just having 1 main flavour. I can create 2 different products from the same project (same source code, with different flows and configurations).
I simplified the question to avoid diving into that part of my project. I know product flavours are an option, but my experience showed me that creating a flavour per brand can take a time, and I wanted to know if there are alternatives worth checking